# Problem with package update-notifier-common after latest updates

Tags: updates, appcenter

After latest updates done trough AppCenter I have following error:

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.168.5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debian/deb822.py", line 47, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named 'six'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have found this: [package update-notifier-common 3.168.4 failed to install/upgrade: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/1680364) but I had 'six' installed before.

I've tried to removing 'six' and installing it again trough 'pip'. It doesn't helped.

Python versions: 2.7.12, 3.5.2, 3.6.3 (also folder named python3 in /usr/local/lib).

OS version: Loki 0.4.1

```
sudo -H pip install six
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages

sudo -H pip2 install six
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

I don't know how to check it for 3.5.2 and this python3 folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Python 3.5.2.

I've found a different way to install packages with 'pip':

```
python3.5 -m pip install foo
```

So I was able to firstly install there 'pip' itself (don't know why I have 'pip' in 2.7 and 3.6 but not in 3.5, my mistake):

```
python3.5 get-pip.py
```

and after that:

```
python3.5 -m pip install six
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem today. After a number of searches on the Stack Overflow site, no desired solution was found. However, I found a solution after searching on a Chinese website, and below are the solution:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg
sudo mv info info.bak
sudo mkdir info
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Ref [here](http://cd%20/var/lib/dpkg%20sudo%20mv%20info%20info.bak%20sudo%20mkdir%20info%20sudo%20apt-get%20upgrade)

Comment: I have no idea why, but this worked for me.

Comment: This helped be on Ubuntu, related to a `apt_pkg` missing module error.